# scroll rest of page once bottom of iframe reached

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to embed a tumblr blog in my webpage using an iFrame.  Unfortunately once I scroll to the bottom of the iFrame and then try and scroll past that I can't.  I have page content below the iFrame that I'd like to see.  How do I enable the ability to scroll the page once the bottom of the iFrame has been reached?

Comment: The iFrame and your page are different pages. Scrolling will occur on which ever one your mouse is over. The browser affects this and you can't control it.

Comment: My desired effect seems to work on my older mac but not my newer one.  I appreciate the input so far but does anyone know why different computers may behave differently with respect to this issue?

Comment: Because browsers. Different browsers will implement this differently....

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, I was using Safari on both computers.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Ok, your not understanding me, you cannot affect this. What you want to do will not work. It works differently because it can and you have very little control over this.